# call an async method before ReactDOM.render()?

Tags: reactjs

I have to call an async method to load some remote configuration values in the LocalStorage.

Is it possible to await an async method before the `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));` and call it once the configuration is loaded ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
async function boot() {
  await loadConfiguration();
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
}
boot();
```

Comment: oh thanks, it was simple :)

Comment: it's not resolving my problem :(, do you know if it's possible to do the same thing in App.js before the `export default App` ?

Comment: No, it's not. If you'd need to do it there, then you need to rearchitect your app so it doesn't expect things to be loaded at import time.